# How to add a new Top menu in ElectronJS without any submenu items?

Tags: electron, vuejs3, electron-vue

```js
[
  {
    role: 'help',
    submenu: [...]
  },
  {
    label: 'Upgrade',
    submenu: [],
  }
]
```

The new menu is also visible if the submenu is an empty array:

[image: Menu screenshot]

I want to show this menu without submenu, which means that when I click on this menu, it will navigate me to a specific action like a button.

Comment: Users don't expect that.  They expect to be able to explore an application by clicking top-level menu items without an action being triggered.  Perhaps Upgrade belongs in the Help menu.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, Thanks for your help.
I want to make sure that this feature can be done or not actually...

Comment: What does that have to do with it?  If you ignore standards and user expectations, you end up with an application that is harder to use and generates bad feelings.

Comment: Hi Client wanted that, there are 2 cases for this new "Upgrade" menu which are "Upgrade" for free users and "Upgrade to Pro" for Premium users.
I have researched and read the documentation of the Electronjs menu but seems like it doesn't.
I want to make sure that by an expert...